# Does each Customer Community Plus user automatically create a Contact record?

Tags: community, contact, customer-community, user-record

When a Customer Community Plus user record is created after someone logs in via the community page linked to an org's web site, is a contact record automatically created for them? Are there any 'gotchas' I should be aware of? 
Thank you so much!
Missy

Comment: Does your community have self registration??? How are they logging in?

Comment: Yes, they self register via a form on the WordPress web site (which is basically communities). [Sorry, I thought I had SE to email me anytime there was a comment; thanks for your quick reply @cricketlang]

Comment: Yes it is. It will be associated to whatever you have the self registration account set as. You can view this in the communities settings for the said community. It may also be set in a custom controller somewhere but most likely that's where you'll find it.

Comment: Excellent! Do you know if an affiliated contact could be created? This organization is on the NPSP v 3.62 and that might be better. Also, I'm not seeing how to mark your answer as best, but perhaps that's because it's a comment and not an answer. Thanks @cricketlang !

Comment: I can mark it an answer if that's the case. I'm pretty sure your org has access to flows and process builder, but I'm not quite certain. If you can validate you do, you could easily write a headless flow that could create another contact and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks @cricketlang, that's a great idea! Yes, please mark it as an answer as this is all super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Any Customer Community user has to have an associated user record, so using Self Registration where a contact with that email does not already exist the default behaviour is:

1. Create Contact record - this will be associated with a default account which is set in the Login & Registration section of the Community Workspace Administration.
2. Create user record linked to the Contact record using the default profile set in the Workspace, under Login & Registration. The profile will have to be associated with the community in Workspace>Administration>Members before the default profile is set.
3. Send user new member welcome email with a link to set the password. This can be configured in the Email section of community Administration.

The main issue that can occur is if you have a deduplication rule on Contact email and there is an existing record with that email address. The controller for the registration page would need to be amended to lookup the email and not create a contact where a matching record exists.

Comment: An old question, but I thought it was worth adding an answer.